# Edismax query in Solr

Tags: php, search, solr

I am using edismax query in solr as below

```
qf = search
```

search field contain following data

```
audi
bmw
land rover
aston martin
```

search only work for one word

ie.

```
q = bmw audi
```

produces result with following data

```
bmw
audi
```

q = bmw land rover

it does not give anything in result, but

q = audi "land rover"

return desired result

Is it possible that i will get result just by typing

q = audi land rover

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are indexing your data, you have to use an analyzer like `WhiteSpaceTokenizer` as describe in [Solr documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers#Tokenizers-WhiteSpaceTokenizer):

```xml
<analyzer>
   <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

This will index tokens like `audi`, `land`, `rover`, ...

Comment: I used same approach and it worked like gem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AND` and `OR` in solr (lucene)

```
q = audi OR "land rover"
```

Please try this one

Comment: I have a textbox where user can type anything. if a user is typing 'bmw audi' we are getting result but not in case of 'land rover' or 'audi land rover'.

Comment: please replace "space" with OR
i mean  "bmw audi" ==>bmw OR audi

Comment: search have two rows

`audi`
`land rover`

q = audi

gives result 

but 

q = aston martin 

not??

Comment: Actually it parse it like
`+((search:land) (search:rover)) ()`

It should be like `+((search:land) (search:rover) (search:land rover)) ()`